# shell-scripting-program show the process hierarchy of that specified process till the parent process whose process id is 1

Tags: shell

Write a shell program to enter the process id of a particular process and show the process hierarchy of that specified process till the parent process whose process id is 1.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
(which pstree > /dev/null || sudo apt-get install psmisc -y) && pstree -ps "$1"
```

- `-p`: --show-pids
- `-s`: --show-parents